# Can I install MySQL and MariaDB both on Ubuntu 16.04 and connection with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have been using MySQL since long but no idea at all about MariaDB and wanted to learn. Before I install MariaDB I would like to know whether it is possible to install along with MySQL and connect it with phpMyAdmin interface or any other interface?

Comment: Use another "port" for 1 of them

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is possible. MariaDB is highly compatible with MySQL

   - "MariaDB intends to maintain high compatibility with MySQL, ensuring a "drop-in" replacement capability with library binary equivalency and exact matching with MySQL APIs and commands"
2. Yes, it can be accessed using phpMyAdmin

   - "Here is a list of tools that are known to work properly with MariaDB: - phpMyAdmin – a web-based database management application for MySQL "

source - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB